# How to use logstash to read multiple csv files?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have 2 *.csv files.

Customers.csv

```
CustomerID,CustomerName,ContactName,Country,CustomerCreateDate
1,Alfreds Futterkiste,Maria Anders,Germany,2022/4/1
2,Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados,Ana Trujillo,Mexico,2022/5/3
3,Antonio Moreno Taquería,Antonio Moreno,Mexico,2022/4/23
```

Orders.csv

```
OrderID,CustomerID,OrderDate
10308,2,1996/9/18
10309,37,1996/9/19
10310,77,1996/9/20
```

Is it possible to use Logstash and Elasticsearch to create a data view that contains `CustomerID`, `CustomerName`, `ContactName`, `Country`, `CustomerCreateDate`, `OrderID`, and `OrderDate` fields.

I know that I can create a data view that contains `CustomerID`, `CustomerName`, `ContactName`, `Country`, and `CustomerCreateDate` fields with this `logstash.conf`.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/Customers.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["CustomerID","CustomerName","ContactName","Country","CustomerCreateDate"]
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "logstash_internal"
        password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
        index => "customers"
    }
}
```

And I know that I can create a data view that contains `OrderID`, `CustomerID`, and `OrderDate` fields with this `logstash.conf`.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/Orders.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["OrderID","CustomerID","OrderDate"]
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "logstash_internal"
        password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
        index => "orders"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to merge the above two data views into one?

Answer (score 0):

There is a not good idea to do. you can create two pipeline logstash files, like: `orders.conf`, `customers.conf`, the `orders.conf` file look like this(It's uses `CustomerID` for `document_id`):

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/Orders.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["OrderID","CustomerID","OrderDate"]
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "logstash_internal"
        password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
        document_id => "%{CustomerID}"
        index => "orders"
    }
}
```

the `customers.conf` like this(It updates the document by `document_id`):

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/Customers.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["CustomerID","CustomerName","ContactName","Country","CustomerCreateDate"]
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "logstash_internal"
        password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
        document_id => "%{CustomerID}"
        action => "update"
        index => "customers"
    }
}
```